# errors using multi plot (ggplot2) and grid.arrange (gridExtra)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a graph with three panels. I am trying to use the functions multi plot (of ggplot2) and grid.arrange of (of gridExtra). None of them work! 
How could I fix this problem???

```
multiplot(f1.1,f1.2,f1.3)
Error: could not find function "multiplot"

grid.arrange(f1.1,f1.2,f1.3)
Error: No layers in plot
```

Comment: I don't think that **ggplot2** has any function called `multiplot`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please carefully read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) and then rework your question to conform to these guidelines.

Comment: I suspect the poster is using code from [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/). Which means one would have to actually load the function on that page.

Comment: How are you generating your plots `f1.1` etc. ?

Comment: This is because you have no geoms just a `ggplot` object.  I can replicate the error with: `f1.1 <- f1.2 <- ggplot2::ggplot(); grid.arrange(f1.1, f1.2)`

Answer (score 5):

Might I suggest installing the gridExtra package:

```
library(gridExtra)
arrangeGrob(f1.1, f1.2, f1.3)
```

Answer (score 4):

Was working on also building graph based on code provided per below blog and was having same issue while using grid.arrange()

Blog : https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/09/comparative-stock-analysis/

```
grid.arrange(High,Low,ncol = 2, nrow = 1)
```

Installed gridExtra() package and re-executed code to resolve issue.

Answer (score 3):

first you have to install the package
install.package('gridExtra')

then use the library(gridExtra)

Comment: How does this answer improve on the answer provided by CuriousCoder? Perhaps a comment that you may need to install the package if you do not already have prior to calling `library(gridExtra)`